# How to render only 5 items in react autosuggest?

Tags: reactjs

I'am using react autosuggest npm package to get the json data and display it. I want to display only 5 items. How to do it?

Form.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Autosuggest from 'react-autosuggest';
import cities from 'cities.json';


const getSuggestions = value => {
  const inputValue = value.trim().toLowerCase();
  const inputLength = inputValue.length;

 // Here I get data from cities.json
  return inputLength === 0 ? [] : cities.filter(lang =>
    lang.name.toLowerCase().slice(0, inputLength) === inputValue
  );
  );
};

const getSuggestionValue = suggestion => suggestion.name;

const renderSuggestion = suggestion => (
  <div>
  {console.log('suggestion', suggestion)}
    {suggestion.name}
  </div>
);

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      value: '',
      suggestions: []
    };
  }

  onChange = (event, { newValue }) => {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue
    });
  };

  onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {
    this.setState({
      suggestions: getSuggestions(value)
    });
  };

  onSuggestionsClearRequested = () => {
    this.setState({
      suggestions: []
    });
  };


  render(){
    const { value, suggestions } = this.state;

    // Autosuggest will pass through all these props to the input.
    const inputProps = {
      placeholder: 'Search City...',
      value,
      onChange: this.onChange
    };

    return (

      <div>  
<Autosuggest
        suggestions={suggestions}
        onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
        onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
        getSuggestionValue={getSuggestionValue}
        renderSuggestion={renderSuggestion}
        inputProps={inputProps}
/>
     <br/>
  </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Form;
```

I want to render only 5 items, otherwise, computer hangs while loading huge data. Is there any other autocomplete react npm package, since I want only cities and country list. i.e when city is inputted, automatically the city name must be suggested with its relevant country.Any solution or suggestion highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: did you tried `slice` the return value of `getSuggestions()`  ?

Comment: yes, but, the data outputted from cities.json is in renderSuggestion() which diplays data. There I want to show only 5 items. How to do it?

Comment: `renderSuggestion()`  will format how you want to display `each` suggestion.

Comment: Ya right! Actually, I want to display only 5 items, I mean when I input single letter for e.g M, then the suggestion must limit to only 5 items

Comment: did you tried my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i modified you're `getSuggestions()` method a little i guess this should work for you.

```
const getSuggestions = value => {
  const inputValue = value.trim().toLowerCase();
  const inputLength = inputValue.length;

 // Here I get data from cities.json
  return inputLength === 0 ? [] : cities.filter(lang =>
    lang.name.toLowerCase().slice(0, inputLength) === inputValue
  ).slice(0,5);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Slice method with start index and last Index

suggestions={suggestions.slice(0, 5)}

Answer (score 0):

```
import { 
    React
    ,Avatar    
    ,axiosbase  
  } from '../../import-files';  
import Autosuggest from 'react-autosuggest';
import './autosuggest.css';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
 
let suggestions = [ { label: 'Afghanistan' } ];
 
function renderInputComponent(inputProps) {
    
    const { classes, inputRef = () => {}, ref, ...other } = inputProps;
 
    return (
        <TextField
            className={classes.textField}
            fullWidth
            variant="outlined"           
             
            InputProps={{
                inputRef: node => {
                    ref(node);
                    inputRef(node);
                },
                classes: {
                    input: classes.input,
                },              
            }}
            {...other}
        />
    );
}

function renderSuggestion(suggestion, { query, isHighlighted }) {    
    return (
        <MenuItem selected={isHighlighted} component="div">
            <div>
                <strong key={String(suggestion.id)} style={{ fontWeight: 300 }}>
                <span className="sugg-option">
                    <span className="icon-wrap">               
                        <Avatar src={suggestion.Poster}></Avatar>
                    </span>
                        &nbsp;
                    <span className="name">
                        {suggestion.Title}
                    </span>
                </span>
                </strong>                      
            </div>
        </MenuItem>
    );
}

function initSuggestions(value) {
    suggestions = value;
}

function getSuggestionValue(suggestion) {   
    return suggestion.Title;
}

function onSuggestionSelected(event, { suggestion, suggestionValue, suggestionIndex, sectionIndex, method }) {   
    console.log('HandleSuggestion() '+suggestionValue);
}

const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
        height: 50,
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    container: {
        position: 'relative',
    },
    suggestionsContainerOpen: {
        position: 'absolute',
        zIndex: 998,
        marginTop: theme.spacing.unit,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        overflowY: 'scroll',
        maxHeight:'376%'
    },
    suggestion: {
        display: 'block',
    },
    suggestionsList: {
        margin: 0,
        padding: 0,
        listStyleType: 'none',
    },
    divider: {
        height: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    },
});

class IntegrationAutosuggest extends React.Component {
    state = {
        single: '',
        popper: '',
        suggestions: [],
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        initSuggestions(suggestions);
    }

    
    // Filter logic
    getSuggestions = async (value) => {
        const inputValue = value.trim().toLowerCase();
        var   _filter = JSON.stringify({
               
            filter : inputValue,
                        
          });

          return await axiosbase.post(`${apiCall}`, _filter);     
    };

    handleSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {

        this.getSuggestions(value)
        .then(data => {                
            if (data.Error) {
                this.setState({
                    suggestions: []
                });
            } else {
                const responseData = [];
                data.data.itemsList.map((item, i) => {                     
                    
                        let File = {   
                            id: item.idEnc,                      
                            Title: item.englishFullName +' '+item.arabicFullName,
                            englishFullName: item.englishFullName,
                            arabicFullName: item.arabicFullName,
                            Poster: item.photoPath,                      
                        }
                        responseData.push(File);                                           
                    
                });
               
                this.setState({
                    suggestions: responseData
                });
            }
        })      
    };    

    handleSuggestionsClearRequested = () => {
        this.setState({
            suggestions: [],
        });
    };

    handleChange = name => (event, { newValue }) => {
        this.setState({
            [name]: newValue,
        });

        if(event.type=='click'){
            if(typeof this.props.handleOrderUserFirstNameChange === "function"){     
                this.props.handleOrderUserFirstNameChange(newValue);
            }               
            
            this.state.suggestions.filter(f=>f.Title===newValue).map((item, i) => {                
                //id
                //Title
                // Poster
                if(typeof this.props.handleUserIDChange === "function"){
                    this.props.handleUserIDChange(item.id);
                  }                
            });
        }
    };

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        // console.log('Re-render!!');
        // console.log(this.props);
        // console.log(this.state.suggestions);

        const autosuggestProps = {
            renderInputComponent,
            suggestions: this.state.suggestions,
            onSuggestionsFetchRequested: this.handleSuggestionsFetchRequested,
            onSuggestionsClearRequested: this.handleSuggestionsClearRequested,
            onSuggestionSelected: this.props.onSelect,
            getSuggestionValue,
            renderSuggestion,
        };
 
        return (
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <Autosuggest
                    {...autosuggestProps}
                    inputProps={{
                        classes,
                        placeholder: this.props.placeHolder,
                        value: this.state.single,
                        onChange: this.handleChange('single'),
                    }}
                    theme={{
                        container: classes.container,
                        suggestionsContainerOpen: classes.suggestionsContainerOpen,
                        suggestionsList: classes.suggestionsList,
                        suggestion: classes.suggestion,
                    }}
                    renderSuggestionsContainer={options => (
                        <Paper {...options.containerProps} square>
                            {options.children}
                        </Paper>
                    )}
                />
                <div className={classes.divider} />
                
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(IntegrationAutosuggest);
```